# How to press back button in android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

In my app I have a logout functionality. If user clicks logout it goes to home screen. Now I am  exiting my app by pressing back button. But what I want is I need to exit automatically(i.e Programmatically) as same like as back button functionality. I know by calling finish() will do the functionality. But the thing is it goes to the previous activity.

Comment: Even if you press back button previous activity will be shown...

Comment: just use finish();

Comment: @Tarun I am using this code to clear all the history ExitActivity.this.finish(); 
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(ExitActivity.this,PinActivity.class);  
    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   
    startActivity(intent1);

Comment: @user1216003 you are on right way. you will do same as back button with setting the flag in intent.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

`onBackPressed()` is supported since: **API Level 5**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //this is only needed if you have specific things
    //that you want to do when the user presses the back button.
    /* your specific things...*/
    super.onBackPressed();   
}
```

Comment: What is the point of this? you are writing what android does by default. It calls onBackPressed() when back button is pressed.... am I right?

Comment: @KKD if you have to support API below 5 then you have to use like above.. http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html

Comment: Then onBackPressed is good to go... Start your ExitIntent inside onBackPressed()

Comment: Thanks for your comment i am not using back button.. I am using a logout button.. when user clicks it populate dialog asking yes or no.. if yes it goes to the home screen where i have to exit automatically but i stuck there... This is need because i am using alarm functionality in my app.. when ever the alarm popup the message the home screen coming background of it.. So i need to remove it thats what i am trying...

Comment: I had problems with onBackPressed() on some tablets, as in crash.

Comment: I have the following code in my second Activity: `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` How do invoke the "Back to main activity"?

Comment: @SiKni8 you can call `getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

Answer (score 46):

You don't need to override `onBackPressed()` - it's already defined as the action that your activity will do by default when the user pressed the back button. So just call `onBackPressed()` whenever you want to "programatically press" the back button.

That would only result to `finish()` being called, though ;)

I think you're confused with what the back button does. By default, it's just a call to `finish()`, so it just exits the current activity. If you have something behind that activity, that screen will show.

What you can do is when launching your activity from the Login, add a CLEAR_TOP flag so the login activity won't be there when you exit yours.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.. It sounds good, but i tried your approach again end up in the same login screen.. Could you help me out from this...

Comment: This is the correct answer, but you should edit it because it's not always "just a call to finish()".  In my case (and it works exactly as I intend) it's a way to move backwards through the fragment stack, and doesn't call finish() until you've gotten to the very first item on that stack.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes is useful to override method onBackPressed() because in case you work with fragments and you're changing between them if you push backbutton they return to the previous fragment.

Comment: This is precisely correct and deserves more upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

Call `onBackPressed` after overriding it in your activity.

Comment: Thanks for you comment.. OnBackPressed i can insert code when back button is pressed.. What i want is i want to call the back button automatically... am i clear

Comment: do one thing... wherever you want to call, whenever you want to call just call this function. you can call it inside onCreate based on a flag or any event you want.

Answer (score 3):

you can simply use `onBackPressed();`

or if you are using fragment you can use getActivity().onBackPressed()

Answer (score 1):

**For Kotlin users and working with fragments:**

use `finish()` if you are navigating through activities, but for fragments you can remove the fragment by its fragment tag.

When navigating to the fragment use:

```
myFragment = myFragment(this)            

parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                .add(R.id.baseFragmentContainer, myFragment, "MYFRAGMENT")
                .addToBackStack("myFragmentNameInStack")
                .commit()
```

then, when tapping your particular button and simulate a "back button" pressing, do the following:

```
    binding.someButton.setOnClickListener {
        activity?.supportFragmentManager?.
        popBackStack("myFragmentNameInStack", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
    }
```

This will remove the fragment added by tag `"myFragmentNameInStack"`, showing on screen the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `finish();` in your first class' (login activity) onPause(); method. that's all

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

// make sure use in outside of onCreate Method