# Action bar home button crashes while back button works

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm completely stumped on this one. I have an activity C, when I try and press the back button, it works. But when I use the home/up button in the action bar it just crashes with (see the following error). Here are the parts of my code which deal with the back/up buttons.

Activity C:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_offline_viewer);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

    @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(!isOnline) {
        menu.removeItem(R.id.saveRoute);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.offline_viewer, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed(); 
    finish();
} 

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{       
    //Get names for saving
    String[] startParts = onlineFrom.split(",");
    String startName = startParts[0] + "," + startParts[1]; 
    String[] endParts = onlineTo.split(",");
    String endName = endParts[0] + "," + endParts[1]; 
    System.out.println(item.getItemId());
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    //Save xml file or route once pressed
    case R.id.saveRoute:
        //TODO:Uncomment once server is ready
        new DownloadFileFromURL(this, startName, endName).execute(urlForDownload);
        return true;       
    case android.R.id.home: 
        System.out.println(item.getItemId());
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Error:

```
08-22 16:15:43.629: W/dalvikvm(4908): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x41c7e888)
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908):     at     com.example.otpxmlgetter.OfflineViewer.onOptionsItemSelected(OfflineViewer.java:185)
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2590)
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:361)
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$3.onClick(ActionBarView.java:167)
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17354)
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5232)
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
08-22 16:15:43.634: E/AndroidRuntime(4908):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does this have something to do with the fact that there are two possible ways to get to Activity C? Either A->B->C or A->D->C? 
The fact that the back button still works completely confounds me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is commonly not recommended to call Activity life cyle methods. The `onWhatEver` methods are used by the framework. If you want to finish the activity rather use ...

```
this.finish()
```

or ...

```
getActivity.finish()
```

if you are in a fragment context.

**p.s.s**: `onBackPressed` does actually work (against initial asumption of this answer). See comments below for the root cause of this issue.

**p.s.**: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747420/call-the-hardware-back-button-programatically) proposes `this.dispatchKeyEvent(new Keyevent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));` as an alternative

Comment: i tried replacing the `onBackPressed();` with `this.finish()` and `OfflineViewer.this.finish();` but still i get the same error.

Comment: Did you debug the code and check whether all of your member are not null (`onlineFrom`, `startParts[...]`, `onlineTo`, ...)? Another question: do you use the ActionBarSherlock library? If yes, take care that you have the right `MenuItem` in the method header (`com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem`).

Comment: man that was so stupid on my part. When i did this ` menu.removeItem(R.id.saveRoute);` i forgot about the other members related to it, just needed to check if the startPart where null. Thank you very much!

Comment: @linus: as per this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718789/how-to-press-back-button-in-android-programatically) `onBackPressed()` should work as well, though it is not really recommended. Have you tried this again? I'd update my answer slighty in this case in order to avoid confusions ;)

Comment: I tried both `onBackPressed()` and `finish()` and they both work. And yes, they are the same since `onBackPressed()` still calls finish according to the post.

Comment: Ok I see - read once, that calling some of these `on...` methods does not work. So this was my first idea. Thx for the hint!